# Add menu option to favoured app launcher in Ubuntu dock

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

I can't find the way to add a custom menu entry to a .desktop launcher.

In Unity I was able to add custom menu entries to launcher like "Open customfile.txt" or "Open somespreadsheet.ods". Is that possible in Ubuntu Dock?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Follow the steps below.

1. Copy `.desktop` file associated to your preferred application, say `app-name.desktop` from `/usr/share/applications/` to `~/.local/share/applications/`. You can do this by running the following command in Terminal

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/app-name.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
   ```
2. Open the `.desktop` file using a text-editor, for example by running

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/app-name.desktop
   ```
3. Look for a line beginning with `Actions=`. If there is one, append `My-Custom-Action;` to it. Otherwise, add the following line

   ```
   Actions=My-Custom-Action;
   ```
4. Write the following lines at end of the file:

   ```
   [Desktop Action My-Custom-Action]
   Name=Name of the Option
   Exec=command-you-want-to-run
   ```

   For example, if you want to open Text editor, put `gedit` in place of `command-you-want-ro-run`.
5. Save the file.
6. Click on "*Activities*" and search for the application.
7. Right-click on the application icon and select "Add to Favourites". It should be added to the Ubuntu dock.

Now if you right-click on the newly added application icon in the dock, you should see a "Name of the Option" entry in the context menu which should work as expected.

Similarly, you can other options by adding new `Desktop Action`s and adding the name of the action to the `Actions=` line. For more info see [this](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#extra-actions).

Comment: what does "name of the option" mean?

Comment: It simply means the name/title you would like to see in the context-menu (right-click menu) for the action. For example, for an action to launch the folder containing photos from your holidays, you may use the name "Photos from holidays" or "Open holiday photos" or "Holiday pics" or whatever else you like.